# Why does typescript not allow adding a property after creating an object?

Tags: typescript

If I create an object like so:

```
var object = { firstName: "billy" }
```

and then I add a property on to it like so:

```
object.lastName = "bob";
```

it shows an error.

```
'Property 'lastName' does not exist on type '{ firstName: string; }'.ts(2339)
```

How do I handle resolve this error without adding the property at initialization?

In my case, I have a form type object and I want to reuse it for multiple calls. So in the first case I send the object with only a few properties, in the next case I want to send the object with a few more properties, and so on.

Basically, I want typescript to not care about types for this one object. I was sure there was a object type that allowed this.

Comment: Do you know what the properties are? Or can they be arbitrary?

Comment: @Schwern well I'm testing an api so it's arbitrary. The docs are slightly out of date, so it's trial and error. I've submitted tickets to the repo but I am trying to get it done soon.

Comment: This is kind of why we use ts. When you declare your object, ts infers the type. Thereafter you need to honour that type definition. You could add lastName?: string. Or if you're feeling fancy you could create an interface for your object IObject, then declare your variable as a Partial generic of inner type IObject... As a horrible last resort you could make object type any but that not a great idea

Comment: @monkey indeed. i'm telling typescript to not do the thing it was designed to do. but it's not for everywhere and it's for this case where i add more properties for progressively larger objects in each test case. for now i just used ts-ignore i think it's ok

Answer (score 1):

You can [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) the object's type, including any required properties along with any expected [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) ones:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true&noErrorTruncation=true#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArApsKAuGBvAUASADMBLAJ2gDkBDAW2U2hKLAHMBufAG0opuQH56URi3YBfGAF5s+YmShVamAETwiHDgE8lAGhyj2OBCjQA6Lj1qSYKhEvZA)

```ts
const object: {
  firstName: string;
  lastName?: string;
} = {
  firstName: "billy",
};

object.lastName = "bob"; // Ok
```

---

If you expect a pattern of property names, you can use an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) (which supports [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html)).

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true&noErrorTruncation=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAcghgWwgZygXigJQgYwPYBOAJgDwAGAJAN7LAECWAdgOYC+8SZANFLQywD4A3ACgR+RrSh4ARgCtcwAFyxEKdFCoiAkADN6BWhwgqARDPoAbSyFNcRrUSNkKcwAHSW4RtRvOzTISgAemCoAHkAa2d5RXcEeiIiSwhjPxkIRjlEJkCQsKiY1w9kAFcCNIx-GQsWYDxGPNCI6Jc4xnocSMqoaplbIObCoriACzgDAGE8S0J0gjwAd0bBgCooAFECBYIRKH2DqAA-E9PTkQAFBcgCUCgAcnGpmcJ7qCI8dUY8YCgIAA96FIGlBQJAHsZkPd3AAKABMAGYEQBOACUUFWwREQA)

```ts
type Names = Record<`${string}Name`, string>;

const object: Names = {
  firstName: "billy",
};

object.lastName = "bob"; // Ok
object.middleName = "benjamin"; // Ok
object.surName = "bobbington"; // Ok
object.nickName = "bobby"; // Ok

object.hairColor = "brown"; /* Error
       ~~~~~~~~~
Property 'hairColor' does not exist on type 'Names'.(2339) */
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true&noErrorTruncation=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghiARhAysATgSwHYHMDSEIAzgGpwA2ArhMVALxQAKc6wmlAPAEoQDGAe3QATTsQw5cAGijiseAHwKA3AChVg7OKgDEAK37AAXLATI08gkTKUadRgG9VASABmmdOIBycALYQTACJETAoKEECpVQBfNVVdAz5gADoKOG8-aEZg3UDlKAB6AqgAeQBreP1DZIALOA8AYQEKIQYoYPQBAHdsPMLi8tUgA)

```ts
type MaybeStringKeysValues = Partial<Record<string, string>>;

const object: MaybeStringKeysValues = {
  firstName: "billy",
};

object.lastName = "bob"; // Ok
object.hairColor = "brown"; // Ok
```

---

In response to [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77755545/why-does-typescript-not-allow-adding-a-property-after-creating-an-object?noredirect=1#comment137080466_77755574):

Beware: I don't recommend this pattern, but I'll show it because it seems like it might provide some use here…

You can start with an extremely weakly-typed object, and then (ab)use the behavior of an [assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) signature to functionally assign values to it and simultaneously narrow it:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true&noErrorTruncation=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgazgewO5wPICMBWEDGwUAvFAEoHIBOAJgDwAKVykVoA0hCADRQCuiFOgB8AbgBQ4gGYDCAS2RwoAQwDOqiGwASagHIRUANWUAbPhDoAVKBAAewCHBqrYgtJlwFgvdjfuPnKCYWTQ4uXkNhAApxAEhkXAAuKEtuOIQuZPY02IA3U3NkwzSASmS1DTYXBJwoORdrADJySlo6bKhIqABvOKialRcKfGp6DsiSgG0MkABdEih8swgJAF9JEbhVIhqvZPgkd2w8QgXu1YlxCtCdVX0jAoh+z0JeACITNWBdZQBbCDe7ywCTeJQku0IADpPtsfv8JFBEYiAPTIgB6AH5JNdtHoDMZls8Tt4oG8ABbKORUADCyBM1EBpKwzHQoPBL2AkIpVNp9KoCKRUFRmOx6hueIehIhJLeUmUuWocgcvOoqkZkzeWGWjLeVAgNDeszB4mlkLlCqoSogKqoqgFSOFWJNHMhqmQ-wwwDJmmCYHtKPRTulEkd4iAA)

```ts
type UnknownObject = Record<PropertyKey, unknown>;

function assertHasNewValue<T extends UnknownObject, K extends PropertyKey, V>(
  obj: T,
  key: K,
  value: V,
): asserts obj is T & Record<K, V> {
  (obj as Record<K, V>)[key] = value;
}

const object: UnknownObject = {};

assertHasNewValue(object, "lastName", "bob");
object.lastName;
     //^? (property) lastName: string

assertHasNewValue(object, "hairColor", "brown");
object.hairColor;
     //^? (property) hairColor: string

assertHasNewValue(object, "favoriteColors", ["blue", "red"]);
object.favoriteColors;
     //^? (property) favoriteColors: string[]

object.someOtherProp;
     //^? unknown

object;
/* ^? const object:
  & UnknownObject
  & Record<"lastName", string>
  & Record<"hairColor", string>
  & Record<"favoriteColors", string[]>
*/
```

Comment: So it looks like the last option will allow object with the addition of any property name... but one of the properties is an array. I could set the second type to `any`?

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77755545/why-does-typescript-not-allow-adding-a-property-after-creating-an-object?noredirect=1#comment137080466_77755574) @1.21gigawatts It sounds like this might not be a good fit for structural typing beyond "some unknown object". You could use a type like `Record<PropertyKey, unknown>` which is essentially the widest possible object type and basically means: an object with any valid keys and unknown values at those keys. Beyond that, you could use a hack like I've shown at the end of the updated answer.

Comment: I think this is ok *if and only if* it is just for reading the API. Then the data is normalized into specific types. Alternatively, skip the One Big Blob object; define the types you need and create typed objects on the fly as you read from the API. More information about the problem would help.

Comment: @Schwern the issue is i'm testing a remote api that has different end points. but they accept the same input (object properties) but for output they have different options. so i want to reuse the object with the input the same and add properties for each call. i'm doing the traditional scientific method of try it and check the results. the form object i'm sending is getting errors so i've had to change the properties and the structure and everything all of which ts doesn't like. until i know what the api expects it's trial and error so i want the generic object

Comment: @Schwern and yes the first thing i did was submit a ticket to ask for more details on how to use the api